# Flutter in-app-purchase fails to restore purchase

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133846) to the Flutter repo, but this is very weird. It seems rather like an Apple issue.

Basically, the restore purchase fails with an error. It could be a Sandbox environment stuff, but we can't ship without confirming this in the Sandbox environment.

This code is supposed to send a previously purchased product to my purchase stream,

```
              try {
                await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
              } catch (e) {
                if (e is SKError) {
                  debugPrint(
                      "SKError code: '${e.code}', userInfo: '${e.userInfo}'");
                }
              }
```

But instead, it will emit error in the debug console, and there is no purchased item coming into my purchase stream.

```
flutter: SKError code: '-1202', userInfo: '{NSLocalizedDescription: このサーバの証明書は無効です。“mzstorekit-sb.itunes.apple.com”に偽装したサーバに接続している可能性があり、機密情報が漏えいするおそれがあります。, NSUnderlyingError: {domain: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork, userInfo: {_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState: 0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue: -9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust_desc: <SecTrustRef: 0x7c8a61cd0>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey: 3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: -9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates: [<cert(0x7c9810800) s: mzstorekit.itunes.apple.com i: Apple Public EV Server RSA CA 2 - G1>, <cert(0x7c984c800) s: Apple Public EV Server RSA CA 2 - G1 i: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA>, <cert(0x7c9846200) s: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA i: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA>]}, code: -1202}}'
```

The Japanese part basically says

'The certificate for this server is invalid. There is a possibility that you are connecting to a server impersonating "mzstorekit-sb.itunes.apple.com," and confidential information may be leaked.'

Did anybody encounter this error? How did you manage to work around?

Comment: I have the same issue. It's not related to Flutter. It seems the server-side (https://mzstorekit-sb.itunes.apple.com) certificate for in-apps is broken.

Comment: Thank you for the report ＠Orange Do you know if there is any workaround? Does the same code work in the production environment at least? 

Comment: I tried the same build on production and on testflight. On production, it works without issues so far.

Comment: @Orange turned out to be an Apple Server temporary issue, now it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this turned out to be a simple Apple server issue and is now resolved.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736720

The lesson is, to always check [system status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/). I thought of removing the question, but leaving this for the lesson